# How to scrape paragraphs of a long article?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to scrape paragraphs of a long article? It is made up of the only HTML. There is no CSS, just plain HTML. Luckily, the new chapter title starts with <"strong"> inside the <"p"> tags.

```
<div id="book">
<h3>This is book</h3> 

<p> <strong> Chapter 1 </strong> </p>
<p> Hello World1 </p>
<p> Hello World2 </p>
<p> Hello World3 </p>
<p> <strong> Chapter 2 </strong> </p>
<p> Hello World4 </p>
<p> Hello World5 </p>
<p> Hello World6 </p>
<p> <strong> Chapter 3 </strong> </p>
<p> Hello World7 </p>
<p> Hello World8 </p>
<p> Hello World9 </p>
</div>
```

My goal is to pull out Hello World 1,2,3 / 4,5,6 / and 7,8,9 and store them in variables.

```
param_1 =

<p> Hello World1 </p>
<p> Hello World2 </p>
<p> Hello World3 </p>
```

```
param_2 =

<p> Hello World4 </p>
<p> Hello World5 </p>
<p> Hello World6 </p>
```

```
param_3 =

<p> Hello World7 </p>
<p> Hello World8 </p>
<p> Hello World9 </p>
```

Comment: Code-wise, what have you tried?

Comment: findAll and hardcoded the chapter title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below collect each chapter data into a list. The list is the value of a dict where the key is the chapter name.

Note that the html is treated as xml doc.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)


html = '''<div id="book">
<h3>This is book</h3> 

<p> <strong> Chapter 1 </strong> </p>
<p> Hello World1 </p>
<p> Hello World2 </p>
<p> Hello World3 </p>
<p> <strong> Chapter 2 </strong> </p>
<p> Hello World4 </p>
<p> Hello World5 </p>
<p> Hello World6 </p>
<p> <strong> Chapter 3 </strong> </p>
<p> Hello World7 </p>
<p> Hello World8 </p>
<p> Hello World9 </p>
</div>'''

current_chapter = None
root = ET.fromstring(html)
for p in root.findall('.//p'):
    strong = p.find('strong')
    if strong is not None:
        current_chapter = strong.text
    else:
        data[current_chapter].append(p.text)
for k,v in data.items():
    print(f'{k} -> {v}')
```

output

```
 Chapter 1  -> [' Hello World1 ', ' Hello World2 ', ' Hello World3 ']
 Chapter 2  -> [' Hello World4 ', ' Hello World5 ', ' Hello World6 ']
 Chapter 3  -> [' Hello World7 ', ' Hello World8 ', ' Hello World9 ']
```

Comment: what is the difference between findall('./p') and findall('.//p')?

Comment: @Jang `.//p` is an xpath expression that is looking for a `p` element in any depth in the doc. `./p` is an expression that is looking only for `p` under current element. In this case both are the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
params_array = []

with open('Html_File_Name.html') as html_file:
    for line in html_file:
        print line 
        # This for loop, loops through each line. So replace the print with 
        # proper if/else conditions and extra variables and append to the params_array.
        # You can use line.startswith("<p> <strong>") to find the start and end of paragraphs.
```

Comment: thanks. enough hint with line.startswith()